# Need help optimizing my code for an e-commerce recommendation system

Tags: python

I need a bit of help/recommendations on how I can speed up my code. I have tried to speed it up but I am not sure what else I can do to make it faster.

Here is the sample text in history.txt

[image]

Here is the sample text in queries.txt

[image]

Keep in mind the size of these files will have more data in actuality.

This is the code so far:

```
    import math
    import numpy as np
    
    # Getting all the values in the file accept the first line and creating a list
    history_file = open("history.txt", "r")
    # Getting values of the first line
    first_line = history_file.readlines(1)
    X = list(map(int, first_line[0].split()))
    lines = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in history_file][0:]
    *T, = map(list, {*map(tuple, lines)})
    print(f"Positive entries: {len(T)}")
    No_items = X[1]
    No_Customers = X[0]
    history_file.close()
    
    # Creating a zeros array then adding the values of 1 in the correct position
    vectors = np.zeros((No_items, No_Customers))
    rows = [i[1] - 1 for i in lines]
    # print(rows)
    columns = [x[0] - 1 for x in lines]
    # print(columns)
    vectors[rows, columns] = 1
    # Calculating the number of vector created in the vectors array
    number_of_vectors = len(vectors) * (len(vectors) - 1)
    
   # I am using the scalar product formula here a · b = |a||b| cosθ so I am trying to calculate the angle. 
    def calculate_angle(x, y):
        norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x)
        norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y)
        cos_theta = np.dot(x, y) / (norm_x * norm_y)
        theta = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_theta))
        return theta
    
    
    # # Calculating the Average angle
    total = sum(calculate_angle(vectors[i], vectors[j]) for i in range(No_items) for j in range(No_Customers) if i != j)
    print(f"Average angle: {round(total / number_of_vectors, 2)}")
    
    
    # Calculating the min angle for the queries file
    def angles(a, b):
        minangles = []
        if a != '':
            for i in range(1, int(No_items) + 1):
                if str(i) not in b:
                    minangles.append([i, (calculate_angle(vectors[(int(a) - 1)], vectors[(i - 1)]))])
        return sorted(minangles, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    
    
    # # Sorting the items
    def recommended_item(z):
        order = sorted(z, key=lambda x: x[0])
        output = ""
        for i in order:
            output += ' ' + str(i[1]) + ' '
        return output
    
    
    queries_file = open("queries.txt", "r")
    read_query = queries_file.readlines()
    query_list = [i.strip() for i in read_query]
    for i in query_list:
        print(f"Shopping cart: {i}")
        recommend = []
        found_updated = []
        query_items = list(i.split(' '))
        for x in query_items:
            match, angle = angles(x, i)
            if angle > 90:
                continue
            elif match not in found_updated:
                recommend.append([angle, match])
                found_updated.append(match)
            if angle < 90:
                print(f"Item: {x}; match: {match}; angle: {round(angle, 2)}")
            else:
                # print("Item: " + str(x) + " No match found!")
                print(f"Item: {x} no match")
        print(f"Recommend: {recommended_item(recommend)}")
    queries_file.close()
```

From my testing, the program seems to spend a lot of time on the calculate_angle function so I am trying to make that calculation faster. And any other suggestion on where I can further optimize the code.

Comment: in your `angles` function, theres no point sorting them, just keep a track of the angle you want and return that, or just use `min` if you're just after the minimum value

Comment: the code would benefit from some high level comment - like what method are you trying to implement. If that is some standard method like nearest neighbors in cosine norm, you'll find some hints eg [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337050/how-to-find-nearest-neighbors-using-cosine-similarity-for-all-items-from-a-large)